# How to get Quartz.Server.exe to run my ASP.NET jobs

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net

I have an ASP.NET website that generates documents. Each document takes a while to generate, and there are many document requests, so I am exploring the idea of using Quartz.NET to help pool the requests, persist them through restarts, and deliver them to users for a better experience.

`Quartz.Server.exe` is included in the download, and it appears to be a daemon for running Quartz jobs even when the front-end is not running. This is obviously perfect for a web scenario like mine.

**The main problem** is that Quartz.Server.exe cannot instantiate the job type that I provide.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'quartztest01' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. --
```

This makes sense because my assembly, `quartztest01`, is not in the GAC, and `Quartz.Server.exe` doesn't know anything about my assembly. But a lot of questions are raised when I try to resolve this.

1. I would prefer not to have my assembly in the GAC. How can I accomplish this? Rebuild `Quartz.Server.exe` with a reference to my assembly?
2. Am I even taking the right approach? The front-end, and `Quartz.Server.exe` are using the same data store, and configured as clustered, but I am paranoid that it will operate.
3. Is `Quartz.Server.exe` even meant for production use? It appears to create a sample job which to me indicates it's just meant as an example. Am I supposed to modify this exe to meet my own needs?
4. What is the best way to install Quartz.NET as a legitimate Windows service, instead of this console application?

Comment: installing as service - simple google search - http://jvilalta.blogspot.com/2011/01/installing-quartznet-20-as-windows.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't have to install in the GAC. Just make sure you assembly is either in the same folder as the quartz.dll or that the framework can find it using the usual techniques for locating assemblies.
2. Yes, it's quite common to have the UI act as a client and thus it has to point to the same store. What is not common is to set the scheduler as clustered unless the UI will also be acting as a server.
3. Yes. Quartz.Server.exe install installs it as a service.
4. The link in @James comment is the answer for this.

FWIW, installing Quartz.net as a service is usually a better solution than embedding it into an ASP.Net web app due to the way the web application lifecycle is managed by IIS.

Comment: Thanks - the reason for clustering is that the web app will be scheduling jobs. The service will execute them. To me it seems obvious that because I'm using two "instances" of quartz on the same data store, I need to mark it as clustered. Is this correct?

Comment: The clustering feature is only used if you have more than one server executing jobs. If your asp.net web app isn't running jobs, you don't need to set the scheduler as clustered.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your assembly in the same dir as the server exe, it should load it fine.  You could use probePath too, but not likely needed for this.