# Quartz.net jobs seem to persist after windows service ended

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm new to Quartz.net and just getting a feel for it at the moment. I'm setting up a Quartz.net job to run from my Windows Service.

My Windows service has two modes of initiating a) if the project is run as a windows service, it will run it as a normal service. b) if the project is being run in debug mode from within Visual Studio, it will run an in interactive mode (this is so I can output debug information to the console vs a logger depending on context). It does this as follows in Main() (just an excerpt):

```
if (Environment.UserInteractive && System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) {
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo onStartMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStart", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    onStartMethod.Invoke(myService, new object[] { new string[] { } });
    Console.WriteLine("Service started.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to stop service and finish process...");
    Console.ReadKey();
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo onStopMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStop", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    onStopMethod.Invoke(myService, null);
    Console.WriteLine("Service stopped.");
} else {
    ServiceBase.Run(myService);
}
```

Now within MyService I have the following working, and this job seems ro run correctly as expected:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    IScheduler scheduler = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    scheduler.Start();

    IJobDetail syncJob = JobBuilder.Create<MySyncJob>()
            .WithIdentity("syncJob")
            .Build();

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5)))
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever())
        .Build();

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(syncJob, trigger);

}
```

However when I run my project in debug mode from my Visual Studio, when I stop the service, the console says "Service stopped", but the Quartz.net syncJob seems to keep running (the console output continues) Why would this be?

Comment: What does your `OnStop` look like?

Comment: Nothing substantial in OnStop. Just "GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(GC.GetTotalMemory(true)); GC.Collect();". Do I need to explicitly stop those jobs in OnStop?

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel?   Quartz.Server.exe   See : http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/16/install-quartz.net-as-a-windows-service-and-test-installation.aspx   There is already a code-base for a quartz.net windows service.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572357/how-to-get-quartz-server-exe-to-run-my-asp-net-jobs

Comment: https://jayvilalta.com/quartznetbook/QuartzNetQuickstart.pdf

Comment: @granadaCoder I can think of plenty of reasons not to use the external code-base, TopShelf being just one;  your second comment seems totally irrelevant to the question posed and your third comment points to a document which is rather basic and doesn't really help either since it actually shows a rather convoluted way of shutting down the scheduler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update your `OnStop` method to shutdown the scheduler when your service is stopped.

```
private ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;
private IScheduler _scheduler;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    _scheduler = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    _scheduler.Start();

    IJobDetail syncJob = JobBuilder.Create<MySyncJob>()
        .WithIdentity("syncJob")
        .Build();

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .StartAt(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5)))
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever())
        .Build();

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(syncJob, trigger);

}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    // true parameter indicates whether to wait for running jobs
    // to complete before completely tearing down the scheduler
    // change to false to force running jobs to abort.
    _scheduler.Shutdown(true);
}
```

As a sidenote, you might want to consider using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) which helps dealing with the teardown and setup of windows services without all the boiler plate bits you show at the start of your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for fast, clear answer. Worked perfectly. I should have known. Topshelf looks great as well, wish I'd come across that when I started this service.

Comment: Topshelf and Quartz full sample ?